# Type of property does not match type of accessor mkmapview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties, mkmapview, accessor

I am more of a java person and I am just starting out with Objective C and iPhone programming.

I have been trying this code to (Xcode iPhone programming) to make the iPhone switch between map types (segmented control buttons) but it keeps on throwing "type of property 'mymap' does not match type of accessor 'setMymap'":

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    MKMapView * mymap;
}
@property (nonatomic, readonly) MKMapView * mymap;
-(IBAction)setMymap:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)getLocation;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize mymap;
-(IBAction)getLocation {
    mymap.showsUserLocation = YES;
}
-(IBAction)setMymap:(id)sender {
    switch (((UISegmentedControl*)sender).selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            mymap.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;
        case 1:
            mymap.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
            break;
        case 2:
            mymap.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
            break;
    }
}
....
```

Answer (score 3):

Rename your setMap: method to mapSelectorAction: or something like that. Any method in Cocoa that starts with set followed by the name of a property, and taking one argument, "needs" to be a setter method for that property.

Correct names are very important in Cocoa in particular but Objective-C in general. Review Apple's [style guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html) for more information.